# Whats the problem with the following code?

Tags: tabularx

```
\begin{table}
  \caption{Description of the data sets}
  \newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright \arraybackslash} X}
  \newcolumntype{S}{>{\centering \arraybackslash} X}
  \newcolumntype{T}{>{\raggedleft \arraybackslash} X}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} {>{\setlength\hsize{.30\hsize}}R >{\setlength\hsize{.17\hsize}}T >{\setlength\hsize{.18\hsize}}T >{\setlength\hsize{.17\hsize}}T >{\setlength\hsize{.18\hsize}}T}  % centered columns (4 columns)
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{3}{r}{Average Tree Nodes} & \multicolumn{5}{r}{Average Tree Depth} \\
  \cmidrule(l){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
  Data Set Name & R\_RF & OVA\_RF & R\_RF & OVA\_RF \tabularnewline
  \midrule
  Balance Scale & 103.5000 & 66.1717 & 3.0160 & 2.0111 \tabularnewline
  Car Evaluation & 129.5560 & 42.0550 & 4.8650 & 2.1050 \tabularnewline
  Dermatology & 17.6960 & 10.0304 & 3.5190 & 1.9441 \tabularnewline
  Ecoli & 43.4420 & 10.4885 & 7.9280 & 3.3712 \tabularnewline
  Glass Identification & 46.3860 & 13.9000 & 8.6480 & 4.0284 \tabularnewline
  Hayes-Roth & 14.8810 & 14.1778 & 2.6040 & 2.4626 \tabularnewline
  Iris & 10.0400 & 7.1859 & 3.8080 & 2.5778 \tabularnewline
  Lenses & 7.1740 & 5.7788 & 2.4010 & 2.0374 \tabularnewline
  Soybean (Small) & 6.4750 & 5.1700 & 1.8480 & 1.4020 \tabularnewline
  Statlog (Vehicle) & 150.5020 & 65.4100 & 14.3900 & 10.7180 \tabularnewline
  \midrule
  Average & 52.9652 & 24.0368 & 5.3027 & 3.2658 \tabularnewline
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
 \end{table}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should, at a minimum, replace the header line

```
\multicolumn{3}{r}{Average Tree Nodes} & \multicolumn{5}{r}{Average Tree Depth} \\
```

with

```
& \multicolumn{2}{r}{Average Tree Nodes} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{Average Tree Depth} \\
```

Your `tabularx` environment contains five columns, and it looks like the headers should span column 2/3 and 4/5, respectively.

I would further recommend repositioning the top-left-most header cell. Instead of right-aligning the four numeric columns -- presumably done to achieve alignment of the numbers on the decimal marker -- you may want to (i) use the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package for the four numeric columns and (ii) use the modified centered column type of the `tabularx` package (which I've renamed `C` to avoid a clash with the `S` type defined by `siunitx`...) to make the table span the full width of the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering \arraybackslash} X}
   %% reserve "S" for the column type defined by "siunitx"
\usepackage{siunitx} %% provides the "S" column type
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Description of the data sets}
\smallskip % create a bit of separation between caption and tabular
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l*{4}{S[table-format=2.4]}}
\toprule
Data Set Name 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Average Tree Nodes} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Average Tree Depth} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
& % the use of "C" in next 4 column types ensures that table is expanded to width of \linewidth
\multicolumn{1}{C}{R\_RF} & 
\multicolumn{1}{C}{OVA\_RF} & 
\multicolumn{1}{C}{R\_RF} & 
\multicolumn{1}{C}{OVA\_RF} \\
\midrule
  Balance Scale & 103.5000 & 66.1717 & 3.0160 & 2.0111 \\
  Car Evaluation & 129.5560 & 42.0550 & 4.8650 & 2.1050 \\
  Dermatology & 17.6960 & 10.0304 & 3.5190 & 1.9441 \\
  Ecoli & 43.4420 & 10.4885 & 7.9280 & 3.3712 \\
  Glass Identification & 46.3860 & 13.9000 & 8.6480 & 4.0284 \\
  Hayes-Roth & 14.8810 & 14.1778 & 2.6040 & 2.4626 \\
  Iris & 10.0400 & 7.1859 & 3.8080 & 2.5778 \\
  Lenses & 7.1740 & 5.7788 & 2.4010 & 2.0374 \\
  Soybean (Small) & 6.4750 & 5.1700 & 1.8480 & 1.4020 \\
  Statlog (Vehicle) & 150.5020 & 65.4100 & 14.3900 & 10.7180 \\
\midrule
Average & 52.9652 & 24.0368 & 5.3027 & 3.2658 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

For comparison's sake, here's the look of your original table (with the `\multicolumn` issues fixed per my initial suggestions):

[image]

Comment: @Mico -- the "data set name" header does look better just above the line.  honest!  (the centered "average tree ..." headers are a distinct improvement though.)